# How to use generic method parameters in Map.Entry?

Tags: java, generics

I want to create a method that takes a generic `List` of `Map.Entry`'s. The key should always be of type `String`, the value could be anything.

Then I want to supply the entries as follows:

```
public void test() {
    List<Map.Entry<String, String>> strings;
    apply(strings);

    List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> integers;
    apply(integers);
}

private void apply(List<Map.Entry<String, ?>> entry) {
}

private void apply(List<Map.Entry<String, Object>> entry) {
}
```

But: neither `apply()` methods won't work here.
Sidenote: I cannot change the types of the entries. Means `<String, String>` and `<String, Integer>` must remain as is.

How can I get them into a generic apply method?

Comment: Why do you want a method that takes that specific class, rather than a `Map.Entry`?

Comment: "But: both apply() methods won't work here." because they have the same erasure. Rename at least one of them.

Comment: why don't you pass *key* and *value* as separate parameters?

Comment: @AndyTurner I think the OP means _neither_.

Comment: @BoristheSpider maybe, but [it works with the first only](https://ideone.com/6whJot).

Comment: Of course the 2nd method should just show an alternative in the parameter type (what I tried). As the example won't compile anyway, I did not chose different names here to illustrate.

Comment: @AndyTurner good point, I should definitely be using `Map.Entry`  here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*After [OP's edit to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/48560717/5), making it `List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>` rather than `Map.Entry<String, Integer>`...*

Add the extra bound into the parameter type:

```
private void apply(List<? extends Map.Entry<String, ?>> entry) {
                    //  ^-------^ here
```

This is necessary so the compiler can stop you putting a `Map.Entry<String, Integer>` into a `List<Map.Entry<String, String>>`, for example, which would break type safety.

Answer (score 2):

Make the `apply` method generic:

```
private <T> void apply(List<Map.Entry<String, T>> entry) {
}
```

Note that depending on what you wish to do within the body of `apply`, using the `private void apply(List<? extends Map.Entry<String, ?>> entry)` signature may not be sufficient.

For example, if you wish to change the value of one entry in the list to be the value of another entry.

The following won't pass compilation:

```
private void apply(List<? extends Map.Entry<String, ?>> entry) {
    entry.get(1).setValue (entry.get(0).getValue());
}
```

But this will:

```
private <T> void apply(List<Map.Entry<String,T>> entry) {
    entry.get(1).setValue (entry.get(0).getValue());
}
```